# Deleting a row in xml where it has an attribute equal to something

Tags: javascript, xml, row

I have the following xml, xmlApplicantActivityType:

```
<ApplicantActivityType>
  <Row codeName="ALL" codeDisplayName="- All activity type(s) - " selected="1"/>
  <Row codeName="REVGNMO" codeDisplayName="Reverse Give Notice" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="COLLECT" codeDisplayName="Collections" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="COMPLT" codeDisplayName="Complaint" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="DCOMT" codeDisplayName="Delinquency comments" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="GENNOTE" codeDisplayName="General note" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="PCOMT" codeDisplayName="Prepaid comments" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="SCRNOTE" codeDisplayName="Screening note" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="TFRSITE" codeDisplayName="Transferred to sister site" selected="0"/>
  <Row codeName="TFRUNIT" codeDisplayName="Transferred to new unit" selected="0"/>
</ApplicantActivityType>
```

Now I have a certain condition that if it is true, the row with the codeName="REVGNMO" should not appear/get removed.

```
if (x='Applicant')
{
//remove row with codeName="REVGNMO"
}
```

How do I do that with javascript?

What I did is the following, but I'm getting errors:

```
var a = xmlApplicantActivityType.getElementsByTagName("ApplicantActivityType")[0];
var rows = a.childNodes;
    if(rows)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
          var codeName = rows[i].getAttribute("codeName");


          if(codeName == "REVGNMO")
          {
          refnode = xmlApplicantActivityType.selectSingleNode("//ApplicantActivityType/Row[@codeName='REVGNMO']");

          xmlApplicantActivityType.selectSingleNode("//Row").removeChild(refnode);           
          }

         }
    }
```

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer here:

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_remove.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = xmlApplicantActivityTypeOnly.getElementsByTagName("ApplicantActivityType")[0];
        refnode = xmlApplicantActivityTypeOnly.selectSingleNode("//ApplicantActivityType/Row[@codeName='REVGNMO']");
        a.removeChild(refnode);
```